# Create custom response object with Node.js SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, alexa-skills-kit

I'm building a skill with the node.js SDK for the Echo Show. I want to use the VideoApp feature ([documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/videoapp-interface-reference)) to display a video based on information I elicit from the user. I have the video in S3, and constructed the directive and the entire response object, and called "response ready" like so:

```
var directive = [
    {
        "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
        "videoItem": {
            "source": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/video.mp4",
            "metadata": {
                "title": "Video Title",
                "subtitle": "Subtitle to video"
            }
        }
    } 
];
this.handler.response = buildResponse(directive);
this.emit(':responseReady');
```

I expected the Echo Show to use the response object I generated to display my video, but instead it says "there was a problem with the requested skill's response." It also displays "Invalid directive" in the corner when it says that. Below is the full response object I generate, any help on how to properly launch a video would be appreciated!

```
{
  "version": "1.0",
  "response": {
    "shouldEndSession": true,
    "outputSpeech": null,
    "reprompt": null,
    "directives": [
        {
            "type": "VideoApp.Launch",
            "videoItem": {
                "source": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/path/to/video.mp4",
                "metadata": {
                    "title": "Video title",
                    "subtitle": "Subtitle to video"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "card": null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. I just had to make the video, and bucket it was residing in, publicly readable in S3 permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Also I've found that you get invalid responses if the shouldEndSession attribute is included with the VideoApp.Launch directive.